# Error: cookieParser("secret") required for signed cookies

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I am working on express/node.js and trying to understand cookies  of expressjs and I'm setting cookie like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser());

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.cookie('cookie1', 'This is my first cooke', {maxAge: 1000*60*60*24*7, httpOnly: true});
    res.end('Cookie has been set');
});
```

And accessing cookies as follows:

```
app.get('/readCookies',function(req, res){
    res.send(req.cookies.cookie1);
});
```

But the problem is `signed: true` option when including this one for encoding cookie value during setting the cookie I am getting the following error:

```
Error: cookieParser("secret") required for signed cookies
```

Please help me and thanks in advance

Comment: https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser#api

Comment: But how can I sign cookies? @robertklep

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The error is explaining what you need to do to be able to send signed cookies:

> Error: cookieParser("secret") required for signed cookies

The [Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.cookie) states:

> When using `cookie-parser` middleware, this method also supports signed cookies. Simply include the `signed` option set to `true`. Then `res.cookie()` will use the secret passed to `cookieParser(secret)` to sign the value.

The [`cookie-parser`](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser#cookieparsersecret-options) documentation states:

> **cookieParser(secret, options)**:
>
> - `secret` a string or array used for signing cookies. This is optional and if not specified, will not parse signed cookies. If a string is provided, this is used as the secret.

So everything combined:

- install `cookie-parser` middleware:

  ```
  npm install cookie-parser
  ```
- add it to the Express app:

  ```
  const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

  ...
  app.use(cookieParser('MY SECRET'));
  ```
- make it sign cookies:

  ```
  res.cookie('cookie1', 'This is my first cookie', { signed : true });
  ```
- and read the cookie value back:

  ```
  res.send(req.signedCookies.cookie1);
  ```

Comment: Until I read this question, I never really understood what's going on with cookies, and cookies with signing.  [My notes...](https://dogfeatherdesign.com/using-cookies-with-nodejs-express-way-easy/)

Answer (score 2):

If you set `signed:true` option, you have to set secret key as string as parameter for `cookieParser()` as follows:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
//Set secret key
app.use(cookieParser('your random secret string here'));

//Set/Write Cookies
app.get('/',function(req, res){
    res.cookie('cookie1', 'This is my first cookie', {signed:true, maxAge: 1000*60*60*24*7, httpOnly: true});
    res.end('Cookie has been set');
});
```

Otherwise just leave it blank as follows:

```
app.use(cookieParser());
```

For accessing the signed cookie value, you can try as follows:

```
//Read Cookies
app.get('/readCookies',function(req, res){
    res.send(req.signedCookies['cookie1']);
    //OR, req.signedCookies.cookie1
});
```

Or, you can check cookies from your browser console as follows if you don't set `httpOnly: true` option:

```
document.cookie
```

For destroying cookies try as follows:

```
//Remove Cookies
app.get('/removeCookies',function(req, res){
    res.clearCookie('cookie1');
    res.send("Cookie has been cleared");
});
```

For more details please check [res.cookie(name, value [, options])](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.cookie)

Comment: So signed cookies are a different property than normal cookies? Example, `request.cookies` versus `request.signedCookies`?